# How to test for success on try statement

Tags: applescript

I would like to perform a certain action in case a `try` statement returns success. Is there a way?

```
try --test for valid internet
    do shell script "ping -o -t 2 1.1.1.1"
    --would like to do something here only if above line returns success
on error
    beep
end try
```

Comment: If the `do shell script` _command_ succeeds, then whatever you put directly after it will execute.

Comment: So putting a line below the do shell script such as "set vSuccess to true" will only execute if shell script is successful?

Comment: the "on error" is only testing the first line of a Try statement?

Comment: Any _command_ that fails within the `try` _statement_ will cause the `on error` to trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
    x
    y
on error
    z
end try
```

If x errors, z executes.
If x succeeds, y executes. Therefore, add your desired code at position y.